# Pass Node.js commands while running the file

Tags: node.js, console

I'm building a small application that will be running 24/7. I need to be able to give the app Node.js's commands from the console. 
Currently, if i want to give an additional command to the app i have to edit it's files, kill it then start it again. I want to start it once and be able to run commands from the console.

Comment: try looking at https://github.com/flatiron/prompt

Comment: try this http://nodemon.io/ or https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever